# How to get the URL of the page that called a function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Here is a code sample:

*myMaster.Master*

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="anAction_Click">
```

calls:

*myMaster.Master.cs*

```
protected void anAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ???
            Request.getUrlOfThePageCalling?
            ???
        }
```

**I'm using a master page. How do I get the page that called this action?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close - try [`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) like this:

```
this.Request.Url
```

Comment: thanks! I knew it was simple. By the way, what's the difference between .url and .urlReferrer ?

Comment: UrlReferrer is the URI of the page that the user was previously on.